# Many-to-many relationship error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, dto

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, and I'm creating an app for attending music events. There is a button for user to follow an artist to get all upcoming events.

When clicking on that button I get an error:

> Entities in 'ApplicationDbContext.Followings' participate in the 'ApplicationUser_Followees' relationship. 0 related 'ApplicationUser_Followees_Source' were found. 1

This is the code of the model:

```
public class Following
{
    public ApplicationUser Followers { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Followees { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string FollowerId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string FolloweeId { get; set; }
}
```

and this is code of the fluent api to build the data :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Following> Followings { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                    .HasMany(u => u.Followers)
                    .WithRequired(f => f.Followees)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                    .HasMany(u => u.Followees)
                    .WithRequired(f => f.Followers)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

This is the controller for the following api :

```
public class FollowingsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public FollowingsController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Follow(FollowingDto dto)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(userId);

        var exists = _context.Followings.Any(f => f.FollowerId == userId && f.FolloweeId == dto.FolloweeId);

        if (exists) 
             return BadRequest("The following already exists");

        var following = new Following
                            {
                                FollowerId = userId,
                                FolloweeId = dto.FolloweeId
                            };

        _context.Followings.Add(following);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is the dto object :

```
public class FollowingDto
{
    public string FolloweeId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the frontend code for the homepage where the following button is located:

```
@model Gighub.ViewModels.GigsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<ul class="gigs">
    @foreach (var gig in Model.UpComingGigs)
    {
    <li>
     
        <div class="details">
            <span class="artist">
                @gig.Artist.Name @if (Model.ShowActions)   {
                     <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm js-toggle-following" data-user-id="@gig.ArtistId">Follow?</button>
                }
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    }
</ul>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $(".js-toggle-following").click(function (e) {
                    var btn = $(e.target);
                    $.post("/api/followings", { "FolloweeId": btn.attr("data-user-id") })
                    .done(function () {
                        btn.text("following")
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        alert("something failed");
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
    }
```

and here is applicationuser class :

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Following> Followers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Following> Followees { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Followers = new Collection<Following>();
            Followees = new Collection<Following>();
        }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show /api/followings action pls?

Comment: @Sergey it is included in my question search for FollowingsController

Comment: I just thought that url should be /api/followings/Follow.

Comment: And pls can you show your ApplicationUser class  then? Error is about app user.

Comment: @Sergey I have added the class at the end of the question

Comment: Thanks. Check my answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your db context with this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Following>(entity =>
            {
               
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Followee )
                    .WithMany(p => p.Followees )
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FolloweeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Follower )
                    .WithMany(p => p.Followers )
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FollowerId );
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

and check your db. Maybe you will need to re-migrate.

Comment: can you add more explanation to the solution also what does p,d refers to

Comment: You can select any letters that you like.  p or d were selected randomly.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, the issue looks to be on your ApplicationUser class and mapping the followings.  If this is EF6 or EF Core 5 you can have something like:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
   // ...

   public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followers { get; set; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();
   public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followees { get; set; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();
}
```

This relationship has to be explicitly mapped:
(EF6)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Followers)
    .WithMany(u => u.Followees)
    .Map(u => u.ToTable("Followings")
        .MapLeftKey("FollowerId")
        .MapRightKey("FolloweeId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

EF Core's mapping will be slightly different but should be able to follow the same gist, just need to check up on EF Core 5's many-to-many setup supporting non-declared linking entities.

Alternatively you can map it out with a "Following" entity, (required for EF Core < 5) but this changes the relationship somewhat because it acts more like a Many-to-One-to-Many rather than Many-to-Many:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
   // ...

   public virtual ICollection<Following> FollowingsAsFollower { get; set; } = new List<Following>();
   public virtual ICollection<Following> FollowingsAsFollowee { get; set; } = new List<Following>();
}

public class Following
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("Follower")]
    public int FollowerId {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Followee")]
    public int FolloweeId {get; set;}

    public virtual ApplicationUser Follower { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Followee { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping then looks like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Following>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.Follower)
    .WithMany(u => u.FollowingsAsFollower)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Following>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.Followee)
    .WithMany(u => u.FollowingsAsFollowee)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This looks rather odd with the linking table since we are mapping a many-to-many self-referencing. I mixed the configuration between attribute and modelBuilder but you will need at least some explicit modelBuilder/EntityTypeConfiguration mapping for the relationships because of the self-referencing types. EF's conventions for automatically mapping relationships are based on the navigation property *type* rather than the property names, so setting up multiple relationships for the same type need to be explicit.

The issue will likely be trying to set up a single `Following` in the user for Followers/Followees. There needs to be two collections for this self-referencing relationship because the "Following" table is expecting a direct relationship between the FollowerID on it's end to marry to the Follower IDs in a collection on the other end. A many to many relationship set up between two tables will have collections on each table so that a Student will list all Courses and a Course will list all Students. With a self-referencing table the same thing applies. A Follower needs to list all Followees, and a Followee needs to list all Followers. It won't work if it's expecting to resolve a collection where I might be a Followee or Follower.  Alternatively you can always do away with the collection on Application user and just have a 1-way many-to-one on Following to go to and resolve the applicable users.